# Provide stdin input from file in cmd?

Tags: python

I am creating a file `input.txt` to store my input and while running my py script file from `cmd`. I want it to take input from that file, just like we can do something like that in c++.

`a.exe < input.txt`

How can we do something similar in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python works the same way. `a.py < input.txt` and `python a.py < input.txt` both work. You can read the file with `sys.stdin` or the `input()` function.

Comment: It with noting that CPython being written in C is entirely irrelevant. Being able to write `python a.py < input.txt` is entirely a property of the shell and will apply to _any_ executable regardless of what language it is written in.

Comment: @Brian its not a property of the shell either. I only made the comment because a cpython program is a C program. But I'll remove it.

Comment: Actually we can use ```python script.py  < input.txt ``` the only thing is we need to specify the path of ```.txt``` file also, this was the thing I corrected and it worked! Thanks to everyone suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

With the main code ready to use once you extract the input, this is the code for doing the extraction of the input from input.txt:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

for line in lines:
  storeInput = line

....
```

what ever the next piece of code would be to use the input from file.

So just working with the input.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help you to handle inputs in python from a textfile:

```
with open("File_name.txt", "r") as file:
       for line in file:
              #Do something with the line in the file
```

[This link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_read.htm) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for :

```
import sys

variable_string = sys.stdin.readline ()
print (variable_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `a.exe < input.txt` is a command to the shell. This method of running an executable will work regardless of what language `a.exe` was written in.

To send the contents of `intput.txt` to a python script, simply run it with

```
python a.py < input.txt
```

The contents of stdin may then be accessed via [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin).

For example, `a.py` might read

```
import sys


contents = sys.stdin.read()
print(contents)
```

which will print the contents of `input.txt` verbatim to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `input()` with `< filename` would do:
for program:

```
x, y = input().split(',')
print(x, y)
```

In shell:

```
username:/home/path$ python test.py < input.txt
1 2
```

Comment: This only works for a single lined `input.txt` and assumes its a comma separated file with two items.

Comment: Of course the program is written that way. Of course the programmer would know the structure the input is going to look like. This is just an example to show that it can be done with `input()`, the usecase will vary.